# CSS Transparent Table Borders

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The quickest way to demonstrate this is https://jsfiddle.net/9jL30wjh/1/

I have a responsive table that stacks on a mobile device.  Pretty simple but I want the white borders on the table to be transparent through to the body background.  If I set the borders to transparent then the background of the actual cell is shown so the whole table looks like a block colour (actually an opacity but I don't think this matters).  That makes sense I guess but since I cant have a margin on the table cells, I can't decide how to work around this or even if I can in this setup.  Can anyone shed any light?

I am using the following CSS for a display: table layout.

```
     body {
        background-color: #3498db;
        color: #fff;
     }

    .pcp-table {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;    
        width: 100%;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
    }

    .pcp-table__row {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        background: transparent;
    }

    .pcp-table__cell {
        display: table-cell;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border-right: 7px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
```

Comment: Adding border: transparent; to .pcp-table__cell gives the desired result?

Comment: I can't understand the problem, but @silviagreen 's comment makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the border becomes transparent but the background of the cell becomes visible, not the background of the outercontainer which is the desired result.

Comment: The result of the transparent border https://jsfiddle.net/9jL30wjh/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive I achieved your desired effect. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouj2842v/1/).

All that I do was add the following lines of code

```
    .pcp-table {
      border-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .pcp-table__cell {
      border: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .pcp-table {
        border-spacing: 0;
      }

      .pcp-table__cell {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
      }
    }
```

The trick was not to use an actual border but to simulate it using either **border-spacing** or **margins**.

**Later edit**: [Another cool way](https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) to achieve this effect is by using `background-clip: padding-box;` combined with `border-color: transparent;`. You can see this example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouj2842v/2/).

From **background-clip** [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

> The **background-clip** CSS property specifies whether an element's background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border.

Comment: Thanks very much, I appeared to be having problems with the margin and did try border-spacing - however I probably had set border: none which is the nuance, I suppose the border-spacing is ignored if you have no border at all other than border: 0 which would set a border of width 0 is that correct?

Comment: @DanMcDaid No, the **border** property can be combined with **border-spacing** just fine. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouj2842v/4/)